# How to display Laravel Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-pagination

I am getting Data using Eloquent by the following way and with pageinate

```
$BlogData = BlogModel::paginate(2);
```

I am getting 2 coloumn in the target page but i don't know how to display the pagination in the view.

I tried to display

{{ $paginator->getUrl($paginator->getCurrentPage()+1) }}

{{$paginator->links();}}

But it throws error `Undefined variable: paginator (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\app\views\Blo`

[image]

How can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing the `$blogData` to the view, you just need to use `{{$blogData->links}}` in the blade template. Is very clear how to use it in the official docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination

Comment: I tried the same , but i didn't got it , Even the code was inside the foreach

Comment: @BizDevB u dont add the {{ $blogData->links() }} inside the loop ,u put it out side like a normal div , also {{$paginator->links();}} will give error because of the `;`

Comment: It came awesome **http://localhost/blog?page=2** Can i change it like **blog/2** like this

Comment: i believe not ,u can add more strings to it ,make the pagination button go to somewhere else but no u cant remove the `page=` part.

Comment: @BizDevB: The paginate need to be outside the foreach loop, and you can make some tricks hack the urls [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305857/laravel-pagination-redirect)