# 301 Redirect w/ 2 GET variables using ReWrite Map

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, get, rewritemap

I am trying to 301 redirect based on two GET variables in this URL: http://www.jwsuretybonds.com/surety-bonds/surety_bond.php?bond_form_id=171&bond_type_id=45

I want to redirect it to: http://www.jwsuretybonds.com/surety-bonds/commercial-bonds/contractor-license-bonds/california/#qual

It appears the solution on this ([301 Redirecting URLs based on GET variables in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871511/301-redirecting-urls-based-on-get-variables-in-htaccess)) Stack Overflow post is the best practice, but I have no experience with Apache and do not know how to modify this to work with 2 GET variables.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Main question is, do you have access to the server config file as root so you can properly make the needed changes for the RewriteMap?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a htaccess file in your document root, here's a 95% start, it is simplified a bit because you don't really care about the values or other query string parameters:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "bond_form_id=171&bond_type_id=45"
RewriteRule surety-bonds/surety_bond.php http://www.jwsuretybonds.com/surety-bonds/commercial-bonds/contractor-license-bonds/california/#qual [R]
```

Comment: That was very helpful.  Thank you!  After a couple of modifications, I got it working great!       [code]
RewriteRule surety-bonds/surety_bond.php http://www.jwsuretybonds.com/surety-bonds/commercial-bonds/contractor-license-bonds/california/#qual? [L,R,NE=301][/code]