# how to change Url format of laravel paginate using Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, url-routing, laravel-5.3

How can I change Laravel page render url to this format.

```
http://exampel.com/articles?page=1
```

to

```
http://exampel.com/articles/page/1
```

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974404/laravel-pagination-pretty-url

Comment: @CannotFindSymbol Why When This is possible with Htaccess I use custom codes ? :|

Comment: Here is something that might interest you  (server configuration to redirect ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871511/301-redirecting-urls-based-on-get-variables-in-htaccess. Now sure how you wanna implement it though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should implement pagination by yourself or use the included one

Here is the docs

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination
- [Paginate class](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html)
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-parameters

Or the simple implementation

you should specify your route, get result from database (or wherever you want), than slice the result array

```
Route::get('articles/page/{id}', function ($id) {
    $articles = Article::all(); 
    $count = 15; //how many items per page
    //of course you should check if $id is not < 0 etc... 
    return view()->with([
        'articles' => array_slice($articles, $id*$count, $count)
   ])
});
```

Comment: cant use htaccess?