# 301 Redirect with URL variables

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Iam trying to do 301 redirection. But it doesnt get redirected.

My old URL : https://www.example.com/category.php?filter=Short%20Term%20Renting

My new URL : https://www.example.com/services/short-term-renting

My code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]&)*filter=Short%20Term%20Renting(&|$)
RewriteRule ^category.php/services$ /short-term-renting? [L,R=301]
```

I referred with this link "[301 Redirecting URLs based on GET variables in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871511/301-redirecting-urls-based-on-get-variables-in-htaccess)"

Comment: Where is `bunch\.of` in https://www.example.com/category.php?filter=Short%20Term%20Renting ?

Comment: `category.php/services` is not part of that old URL either.

Comment: @04FS category.php/services is the part of the new URL

Comment: Yes, but the first part of a RewriteRule is the _old_ URL path you want to match.

Comment: I followed this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871511/301-redirecting-urls-based-on-get-variables-in-htaccess"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching `^category.php/services` whereas `services` is not present in your current request URI. Also, I would suggest matching query string regardless of the case of characters.So, your `.htaccess` should look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*?filter=Short%20Term%20Renting$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category.php$ /services/short-term-renting? [NC,L,R=301]
```

**Demo:** https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=8acfa0a0-cf9e-5036-a245-a5a24bd90b26

**Update:**

If you want to serve the `services/*` URL, yet make an internal request to the same `category.php`, you could do something like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*?filter=Short%20Term%20Renting$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category.php$ /services/short-term-renting? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^services\/(.*)$ /category.php?filter=$1 [L]
```

**Demo:** https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=8f82a119-5cc9-5851-a3fa-ad9171ef6487

Comment: Ok its working fine. But I need 301 redirection like here. So that when I redirect only the name of the URL must change. The content in the web page must be same.